# TCPDF - Set margin left for custom header

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using a custom header in TCPDF.  I would like to set the margin left for this header.

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
       public function Header() {
            // Logo
            $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'uwa_logo.jpg';
            $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 40, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
            // Set font
            $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 14);
            // Title
            $this->SetTextColor(33,64,154);
            $this->Write(0, $this->CustomHeaderText);
        }...

    $pdf->CustomHeaderText =  $presentation_name;
```

Is there a method to do this?

**UPDATE**

Mmm, strangely enough this works:

```
$pdf->CustomHeaderText =  '                               '.$presentation_name;
```

Though I wouldn't necessarily call that an accepted method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough: create a `GetLeftMargin()` method to access the `lMargin` property (not a strictly necessary step, but highly recommended), store the original value, set the title margin, do your normal write action, then finally revert the margin afterward.

An example might look something like this:

```php
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // Margin
        $old_margin = $this->GetLeftMargin();
        $this->SetLeftMargin(/* Your new margin here. */);

        // Logo
        $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'uwa_logo.jpg';
        $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 40, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 14);
        // Title
        $this->SetTextColor(33,64,154);
        $this->Write(0, $this->CustomHeaderText);

        // Revert margin
        $this->SetLeftMargin($old_margin);
    }

    public function GetLeftMargin() {
        return $this->lMargin;
    }
}
```